# CMDeviceMotion in landscape orientation

Tags: ios, core-motion

I have been working on an app that uses a side-to-side tilt motion gesture. I have it working using the CMDeviceMotion data via the CMQuaternion values to get "roll" via [Using quaternion instead of roll, pitch and yaw to track device motion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19239482/1408431) but I have one weird bit of behaviour where the output will sometimes work perfectly and others not.

The app is locked to landscape orientation (both ways) but I have noticed that if I start the app held in portrait orientation my roll code works perfectly with a pi/2 modifier. If I open the app with the device held in landscape it works on pitch with no modifier.

The problem is that I have no way of knowing which to use! Is there some way of detecting or reseting the frame of reference?

UPDATE:

I tell a lie, if I start in landscape orientation it seems to just pick a random axes :( I assume this is again a Gimbal Lock thing but the original question still applies - how do I get this to be consistent when I start the device in a landscape orientation?

UPDATE 2:

Some token code (coming from a NSNotification) for people who can't read and feel the need to downvote without.

```
CMDeviceMotion *data = [[note userInfo] valueForKey:@"data"];
CMQuaternion quat = data.attitude.quaternion;
CGFloat roll  = atan2(2*(quat.y*quat.w - quat.x*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.y*quat.y - 2*quat.z*quat.z);

CGFloat pitch = atan2(2*(quat.x*quat.w + quat.y*quat.z), 1 - 2*quat.x*quat.x - 2*quat.z*quat.z);
CGFloat yaw   = 2*(quat.x*quat.y + quat.w*quat.z);


NSLog(@" - - ");
NSLog(@"raw roll: %f",roll);
NSLog(@"raw pitch: %f",pitch);
NSLog(@"raw yaw: %f",yaw);

NSLog(@"q.x: %f",quat.x);
NSLog(@"q.y: %f",quat.y);
NSLog(@"q.z: %f",quat.z);
NSLog(@"q.w: %f",quat.w);
```

Launched from `startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue` in AppDelegate.

This is irrelevant however as the issue is that the quaternion data is stable when the device is in a portrait orientation at launch but not with a landscape orientation. What I choose to do with the device data is a totally separate issue.

This is a similar issue without a satisfactory answer (or any code in the question :|) [CMDeviceMotion yaw values unstable when iPhone is vertical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692344/cmdevicemotion-yaw-values-unstable-when-iphone-is-vertical?rq=1)

Comment: If you have code that isn't working as you expect, _show_ your code. Your question talks only in the vaguest generalities; who knows what you're doing, or even what the problem is?

Comment: The code isn't where the issue is. I have taken a calculation using CMQuaternions as I have said but the device output differs and is unstable based on launch orientation - how is that related to my code?

Comment: "how is that related to my code?" Because the only way you know what the "device output" is, is through your code.

Comment: Okay, so you see, you have now added the code and sure enough, I was right. I'm putting my answer back. I was spot on. You are doing exactly what I said you cannot do.

Comment: Ok, I might be being ignorant of the quirks of quaternions and rotationMatrices (I am) but isn't my calculated roll just a transform of those numbers? Assuming not... How would I go about finding out which way is down then selectively detecting a tip left or right - it's for a fake water level progress widget thing. Do you have a link to a decent primer?

Comment: You would do what I said in my answer. For example, having obtained the `rotationMatrix`, you can _apply_ that matrix in your code (for example, as a transform to some visible view). You do not _convert_ to individual angles. (The second half of this section of my book shows how to apply the `rotationMatrix` as a layer's `transform`: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch35.html#_gyroscope)

Answer (score 0):

> my roll code works perfectly

Your "roll code" doesn't work perfectly. You should not have any "roll code". In a situation where you can get gimbal lock, don't use Euler angles at all. You cannot "reduce" to Euler angles such as `roll`. Instead, use quaternions or (easier) `rotationMatrix` and *stay* in that world. You *cannot* "calculate" your way out of the problem by starting with the quaternion and *converting* to an Euler angle. And that is exactly what you are trying to do. If you think this is possible, you have not understood what gimbal lock is (or how `atan` works, perhaps).

Comment: I am using quaternions to calculate a roll for that reason. If I trace all the numbers out I get different sets that respond to tilting to the side if I start in landscape but one consistent set of behaviour if I start in portrait.